# Android - Bluetooth connection dies after few seconds only in Samsung devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, samsung-mobile

I am working on app where I connect my phone with a device that reads EPC labels, the connection is on bluetooth. I managed to read the data recieved from the reader and display it in the UI thread, but the problem is : In Samsung devices after few seconds of labels reading the bluetooth connection dies and I get these messages :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/biQ5U.jpg

Oddly it happens only in Samsung devices, I tried testing in HTC and Sony and it works perfectly, is there any hint about the solution ?